# Cannot pass data from view to controller spring thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I encountered problems trying to pass data from this template:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/pacientes/fechas}" th:object="${fechaInicioFinal}" method="GET">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Fecha Inicio :</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="datetime-local"  th:field="*{fechaInicio}">
                
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Fecha final :</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="datetime-local"  th:field="*{fechaFinal}">

            </td>
        </tr>
        

       

    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="Buscar">
</form>
```

To this controller, where my FechaInicioFinal only receive null values:

```
@GetMapping("/fechas")
public String buscarFechas(@ModelAttribute FechaInicioFinal fechaInicioFinal, BindingResult result, Model model,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {

    LOG.info(fechaInicioFinal.toString()); // Here I get null values


    // Business logic
}
```

This is the Controller where I use the template:

```
@GetMapping("/buscarFechas")
public String obtenerFechas( Model model, FechaInicioFinal fechaInicioFinal) {

    model.addAttribute("fechaInicioFinal", fechaInicioFinal);
    return "p_buscar_fechas";

}
```

I tried already these pages:

- https://bushansirgur.in/spring-mvc-pass-data-from-controller-to-view/
- [How to pass data to from view to controller in Spring-MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64725675/how-to-pass-data-to-from-view-to-controller-in-spring-mvc)
- [Pass data from Thymeleaf template to springboot controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65738633/pass-data-from-thymeleaf-template-to-springboot-controller)
- [Using thymeleaf to post form data to a Controller that uses @ModelAttribute (complex objects)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42192373/using-thymeleaf-to-post-form-data-to-a-controller-that-uses-modelattribute-com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, there was a problem in the FechaInicioFinal class, was without this annotation

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
private LocalDateTime fechaInicio;
```

EDIT : So if there is something you can do to anyone that tried everything like me, before all you should look up for your entities and check if there is something you can do with the format of your columns that could be incompatible with Thymeleaf.

Comment: In cases like this, where you solved your own answers, I suggest evaluating if this question is of interest for anybody. In your case, as the question is very specific and the problem related to an usage mistake, I think you can safely delete this question.

Comment: @YvesHendseth At the beginning, I really though it were a common problem, and as u said, it's kind of specific because of the format of my entity. But I think this could be a solution to anyone who encounter problems with thymeleaf, and the solution is not present in the templates, but instead in their entities. Maybe with a clarification would be better?, see my edit. or should I delete my question anyways?